# PHP make all possible variants of 4char A-Z,a-z,0-9

Tags: php, recursion, permutation

I have to make a list of all possible permurations of 4characters A-Z,a-z,0-9 and conbination of all this.How can i pass thru all of the possible combinations and printf them ?

what's it for:I need to make this in a html document that i can then print and give all this as random unique usernames for our university, so that students can provide feedback based on one unique id that will be invalidated when used. i can not change this procedure into a better one!

Comment: I would also search for permutations

Answer (score 6):

Warning: This takes some time to compute because there are 62^4 = 14776336 possible combinations. It also takes a lot of memory if you accumulate the results and don't print them directly.

```
function print_combinations($characters, $length, $combination = '') {
        if ($length > 0) {
            foreach ($characters as $i) {
                print_combinations($characters, $length - 1, $combination . $i);
            }
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", $combination);
        }
}

$characters = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
print_combinations($characters, 4);
```

Comment: elegant, recursive functions always make me feel fuzzy but it's the best answer imho.

Comment: how to use this function with start index? Ex. generate possible combinations for length from 4 to 6

Answer (score 2):

With a rather unconventional approach, you could use dec2any from the [comments on the php documentation for base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450) like this:

```
$index = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$base = strlen($index);
$len = 4;

for ($i = 0, $l = pow(strlen($index), $len); $i < $l; $i++) {
    echo str_pad(dec2any($i, $base, $index), $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), "\n";
} 

function dec2any( $num, $base=62, $index=false ) {
    if (! $base ) {
        $base = strlen( $index );
    } else if (! $index ) {
        $index = substr( "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ,0 ,$base );
    }
    $out = "";
    for ( $t = floor( log10( $num ) / log10( $base ) ); $t >= 0; $t-- ) {
        $a = floor( $num / pow( $base, $t ) );
        $out = $out . substr( $index, $a, 1 );
        $num = $num - ( $a * pow( $base, $t ) );
    }
    return $out;
}
```

It can be quite easily adapted by changing $index and $len.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little rushed but:

```
class Combinations{

    protected $characters = array();
    protected $combinations = array();

    public function __construct($characters){
        $this->characters = $characters;
    }

    public function getCombinations($length){       

        foreach($this->characters as $comb)
        {
            $this->getRecurse($comb, $length - 1);
        }

    $combinations = $this->combinations;
    $this->combinations = array();

    return $combinations;

    }

    public function getRecurse($combination, $length){

        if($length <= 0){
            $this->combinations[] = $combination;
        }else{
            foreach($this->characters as $comb)
            {
                $this->getRecurse($combination.$comb, $length - 1);
            }
        }

    }

}

$characters = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));

$comb = new Combinations($characters);

print_r( $comb->getCombinations(4) );
```

The number passed to `getCombinations` is how long you want the combinations to be.

Answer (score 0):

More universal approach with delimiter :

```
function getCombinations($base,$delimiter="|"){

    $base = array_values($base);
    $baselen = count($base);

    if($baselen == 0){
        return;
    }
    if($baselen == 1){
        return $base[0];
    }else{
        //get one level lower combinations
        $oneLevelLowerArray = $base;
        $orig_part = $oneLevelLowerArray[0];
        unset($oneLevelLowerArray[0]);
        $oneLevelLower = getCombinations($oneLevelLowerArray,$delimiter);
        $countOLL = count($oneLevelLower);
        foreach ($orig_part as $rowa) {
            foreach ($oneLevelLower as $rowb) {
                $resultArray[] = $rowa.$delimiter.$rowb;
            }
        }

    }

    return $resultArray;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like that? (pseudo code)

```
$a = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));

foreach($a as $key => $b) {
    echo $b.$a[$key+1].$a[$key+2].$a[$key+3].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Heads-up: This'll generate only a handful codes and cause errors. You've got the right idea with the `array_merge`, but you need four `foreach`s if you want to output all possible combinations.

Comment: @pinkgothic, I dont need 4 foreachs, I shift the four chars of one output by one chars each. (+1, +2, +2)

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants all combinations. That's to say, not just ABCD, BCDE, CDEF et cetera, but AAAA, AAAB, AAAC, AAAD, and so on. Your current code doesn't provide that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$numbers = range(0, 9);
$lowerCaseLetters = range('a', 'z');
$upperCaseLetters = range('A', 'Z');

foreach($numbers as $number) {
   foreach($lowerCaseLetters as $lowerCaseLetter) {
      foreach($uperCaseLetters as $upperCaseLetter) {
          echo $number.$lowerCaseLetter.$upperCaseLetter.'<br />';
          echo $number.$upperCaseLetter.$lowerCaseLetter.'<br />';
          echo $lowerCaseLetter.$number.$upperCaseLetter.'<br />';
          echo $lowerCaseLetter.$upperCaseLetter.$number.'<br />';
          echo $upperCaseLetter.$lowerCaseLetter.$number.'<br />';
          echo $upperCaseLetter.$number.$lowerCaseLetter.'<br />';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Heads-up: This generates codes that are only three characters long.

Comment: yea, i need this to get going from  1 char to 4 char.